# bash mv every n files into different subfolders with consecutive names

Tags: bash, unix, ksh

I am trying to move n files in a directory to subdirectories. To be clear, lets say I have a folder named 1999. 
I have 364 files under /1999 which are datafiles for each day. I want to move these files into subfolders named as weeks (1-52). In this case, I want to move 1st-7th files to folder named "1" ,then 8th-14th to folder named "2" and move files 358th-364th to folder named "52". So I need a loop of 7s :). How can I do this in bash or ksh?

Comment: How are your files named? how do you decide where the files go? what do you mean by the _n_-th file? is it with respect to the standard (local) alphanumerical ordering?

Comment: They are named as 1999_001.dat,1999_002.dat etc..001 represents the 1st day of the year.So i want to move files named 1999_001 ,_002,...1999_007 to folder named 1. Then move 1999_008,...,1999_014 to folder 2 and so on...

Answer (score 2):

Here's a pseudocode:

```
Get timestamp of the beginning of the year 1999 as FIRST_TS
Get timestamp of the end of the year 1999 as LAST_TS

For each file in /1999 as FILE
   Get timestamp of FILE as FILE_TS
   SUBFOLDER = (Integer) 52 * ((FILE_TS - FIRST_TS) / (LAST_TS - FIRST_TS)) + 1
   Create folder named as /1999/SUBFOLDER if it doesn't exist
   Move FILE to folder SUBFOLDER
End
```

Tools you can use:

*****  `find` (`find /1999 -type f -maxdepth 1 ...`)
  *****  `date` (`date -r "$FILE" '+%s'`)

Update:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob

YEAR=1999
ROOT=/$YEAR

for FILE in "$ROOT"/"$YEAR"_???.dat; do
    N=${FILE##*_*(0)}; N=${N%.dat}; N=$(( (N - 1) / 7 + 1 ))
    DEST=$ROOT/$N
    [[ -d $DEST ]] || mkdir -p "$DEST" || {
        echo "Failed to create destination directory \"$DEST\"." >&2
        exit 1
    }
    mv -v -- "$FILE" "$DEST" || {
        echo "Failed to move \"$FILE\" to \"$DEST\"." >&2
        exit 1
    }
done
```

Comment: Sorry. I am a total newbie. This does not mean much to me. Do I use date to find the timestamps? This -r displays the last modification time of file. And this '+%s' in date? I checked the manual for date and it is seconds since 1970-01-01 etc.. IS this pseudocode ment to find somekind of Julian day? And I already have the empty folders named as 1,2,3,4....52.

Comment: can't I just do it with something like: 
files="*.dat" 
for i in $files
do ?!?? mv??
done

Comment: Sorry for being a bit cold there. Please see update and see if it would work for you.

Comment: I tested it with dummy files and it works well. Make sure you save it as a UNIX file then run explicitly with bash e.g. `bash script.sh`

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
#!/bin/bash

COUNTER=0
while [ $COUNTER -lt 52 ]; do
  mkdir $((COUNTER + 1))  # Leave this out if the directories already exist.
  mv `seq $((COUNTER*7 + 1)) $((COUNTER*7 + 7)) | xargs print "1999_%03d.dat "` $((COUNTER + 1))
  COUNTER=$((COUNTER + 1))
done
```

But unless you want to stay a "total newbie" for ever you should try coming up with it on your own! If you can completely get everything this snippet is doing you'll be well on the way to understanding shell scripting, so try and read this code, play with it, and see what you can learn from it.